# Bot Skype channel Invalid XML in message text

Tags: botframework, skype

I have created a bot and registered successfully. It is working fine in emulator and web chat but on skype it is not working and I can see issues logged on dev framework page  saying Invalid XML in message text.

can someone please help with this issue.

Thanks
Uday

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the code you are using to send messages as well as the exact "issues logged on dev framework page".

Comment: [Please Read How to Ask on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you tried to send some text, which Skype think is XML. This seems to happen when you did *not* specified your [textFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/bot-framework/portal-channel-inspector#text-formatting) to be XML. Typical your `json` may looks something like this: `"text":"my cmd is send <arg>"`.

Change your `<arg> to < arg >` using space between, or specify XML as your textFormat, and you will be fine.